# Create Story from camera in Flutter

Tags: entity-framework, flutter, storyboard, flutter-plugin

I want to **create a story** in my app just like as we upload story in **snapchat**. In other words when I tap on add story button in my app then a screen should appear to take picture or record video from camera. Please help me how i can make it or if any Fluttrer package is there for that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

check out the [camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) and [story_view](https://pub.dev/packages/story_view) package on pub. You can customize the whole camera package according to your use case.